# Algorithm to compute complete homogeneous symmetric polynomials

Tags: algorithms, symmetric-polynomials

Is there any algorithm to compute complete homogeneous symmetric polynomials efficiently? I was able to find algorithm to compute elementary symmetric polynomials.

Example :- a1 = 2, a2 =3
So for this case n = 2
Now suppose we are given a random positive integer m. Let's say m = 2, then, complete homogeneous symmetric polynomial corresponding to n = 2 and m= 2 is
$$F_m(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 + x*y $$
$$F_2(2, 3) = 2^2 + 3^2 + 2*3 = 19$$

Comment: What do you mean by "compute" here ? Give a list for a given degree ? Please, provide an example.

Comment: I am talking about algorithms for any general n. Suppose you are given with n integers and you put them in complete homogeneous symmetric polynomial, then, what's the value you will get.

Comment: Therefore, if I take an example, as  would have like to see one from you, you mean efficiently computing the value of for example  $ax^6+bx^5y+cx^4y^2+...$ for given $x,y$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie yeah and sorry I didn't add any example

Comment: If you know how to generate a bunch of elementary symmetric polynomials, then you can just solve an appropriate linear system (see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_homogeneous_symmetric_polynomial#Relation_with_the_elementary_symmetric_polynomials)) to get a bunch of complete homogeneous symmetric polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

I was surprised that I could not find an algorithm in python to compute the complete symmetric homogeneous polynomials so I wrote one. Here is my code. The computation is done recursively. It would be much more efficient in a compiled language.

```
def CompPoly(a,n):
    #Returns the complete symmetric homogeneous polynomial of degree n and coeffs a
    if(n>1):
        sum=pow(a[0],n)
        if(size(a)>1):
            for i in range(n):
                sum=sum+pow(a[0],i)*CompPoly(a[1:],n-i)
        return sum
    if(n==1):
        return a.sum()
    return 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method. Is it the most efficient one, I don't know...

A) Let us begin by the case of 2 variables with the concrete example of

$$P(x,y)=a_0x^6+a_1x^5y+cx^4y^2+\cdots a_5xy^5+a_6y^6.\tag{1}$$

(the generalization will be straightforward).

Let us assume that $y \ne 0$ (otherwise, the computation is immediate).

Two steps :

- factorizing $y^6$, we are left with $y^6 Q(x/y)$, where $Q$ is a sixth degree polynomial in the single variable $t=x/y$, then
- evaluate $Q$ using Horner's scheme for example.

B) For a 3 variables polynomial $\sum_{0 \le i,j,k \le 6}a_{i,j,k}x^{i}y^jz^k$,

- factorize $z^6$ : we get $z^6 Q(x,t)$ where $Q$ is a polynomial with variables $x$ and $t=y/z$.
- then apply the method described just before.

C) For $n$ variables, generalize this process in a "recursive way"...

---

Edit : taking account the remarks done, a big simplification occurs. Let us consider again example (1).

$$P(x,y)=(x/y)^6(1+t+t^2+\cdots +t^6)=(x/y)^6 \dfrac{1-t^7}{1-t}$$

Comment: You got the question wrong. We are not given with the polynomial. We have to generate it. I have added an example. Please check that and sorry for inconvenience

Comment: Even with your example, I don't understand... The input of your program is the number of variables and the degree, but also the values of $x,y$. Which output do you want ? The value of the polynomial with all the coefficient being $1$ ?

Comment: you are given n positive integers and another positive integer m. Now, you have to generate complete homogeneous symmetric polynomial $F_m(n)$ and then pass those n integers as arguments to the polynomial and compute the final answer.

Comment: Do you assume always that all your coefficients are equal to $1$ ?

Comment: yeah! They all are 1 always

Comment: Therefore the method I propose is still valuable with a big simplification (see "Edit" to my answer).

Comment: In 3 variable polynomial, if there is a x*y^2*z^3 term and you have taken z^6 out of the whole polynomial, then, this term will become x*y^2/z^3. Clearly, even if you substitute t = y/z, then, this term will be x*t^2/z and z is still not full eliminated.

Comment: I consider that this term is $(x/z)(y/z)^2=XY^2$ and we are exactly back to the situation with two variables ! This process (dividing by one variable) is a kind of "projectivation".

Comment: When we take z^6 term common and substitute X = x/z, Y = y/z, the polynomial left will not be a homogeneous symmetric polynomial and it will also have '1' as one of its terms. So, we can't treat that as 2 variable situation

Comment: I see now : indeed, you get the sum of homogeneous symmetric polynomials of all degrees $\le 6$ in this case.